# Align horizontally several div (with variables width), with spacing between each

Tags: html, css

I searched a lot on this forum but my problem is too specific.
I would like to achieve this, I try for several months but I can not get work... Thanks in advance if anyone can help me :) :)

[image]

I would like to align horizontally 2, 3, 4, 5 or more divs, with variable widths, and with static spacement between each div. And all this must not exceed his parent. So I agree that the 4 div can not do 25% of width, but I do not see how to do ..

Comment: The problem is that 25% x 4 = 100% so that means even 1 pixel padding or margin will be greater than 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a great use case for `flex-box`. I have used the same code for both the cases. The CSS doesn't change, but the HTML does:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: #999;
  margin: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.flex-item {
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  background: #99f;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Item</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Item</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Item</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Item</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Item</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Item</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Item</div>
</div>
```

You **don't** need to change the CSS according to the number of sub elements. I have given the example with three and four `<div>`s.

Comment: It work great :D I just need use a :last-child to set margin right 0 to the last item, but it work great :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @PierreArsenic I did that for you. have a look?